# How to resize cordova Webview on click event of phonegap plugin in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I've integrate phonergap `WebView` in iOS .

**Requirement ::**
How to resize cordova `WebView` when user click on a `Button` (Which is created in Cordova `WebView`).

In my App, Cordova `WebView` is actually added as a subview on my `ViewController`  view.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell you an accurate answer without seeing your code, but you should do something like this:

you have to create a plugin ([see the guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide))

and the native code should do something like this:

```
[self.yourCordovaViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

Comment: Thanks for help me ,But your native code is not work, I've tried already.

Comment: as a told you, it's hard to tell you an accurate answer without seeing your code. Mine works because I use it, but it may need some adjustments in your case.